# In ES6, how the "Tail Calls" avoid the stack overflow?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, stack-overflow, tail-recursion

In ES6 new features, I cannot understand the "Tail Calls", Calls in tail-position are guaranteed to not grow the stack unboundedly. Makes recursive algorithms safe in the face of unbounded inputs.

```
function factorial(n, acc = 1) {
    'use strict';
    if (n <= 1) return acc;
    return factorial(n - 1, n * acc);
}

// Stack overflow in most implementations today,
// but safe on arbitrary inputs in ES6
factorial(100000)
```

I searched but I still cannot understand clearly.

1. Can anyone explain to me why the old javascript(ES5) will have problems with recursive algorithm?
2. How the "Tail Calls" avoid the problem?

Comment: See if https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call answers your question?

Comment: `factorial` can't do anything with the results of its recursive call, because it is its last expression (tail position). Consequently, no stack frame must be preserved.

Comment: @smarx yes, it is a duplication of that link, thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @LUH3417 is that means that most of time, we should avoid use tail call?  I only know this concept today, not very familiar with "tail call", but i think I use it a lot, which probably very risky.

Comment: No, tail recursion is great. Try to use it whenever it suits. Sometimes it doesn't work, such as with tree traversal.

Comment: @LUH3417 Thanks :)